# Saving User and Detail rows with Cake 2.4.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.4

I am very new to cake and I was wondering how i would be able to create a new user and also be able to create the contact details

database is like so

Users

- user_id
- contact_detail_id
- password
- role_id
- username

Contact_Details

- contact_detail_id
- address1
- address2

and many other fields

In the User model I have assigned public $hasOne = array('ContactDetail');

Since the user will have one contactdetail

Now what I need to know is how would this would be saved in the add method as many said to use the saveassociated although this doesn't seem to be working.

The add view is like so and from my understanding this is correct

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'add')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
                echo $this->Form->input('User.password');
                echo $this->Form->input('roles');

                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.name');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.surname');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.address1');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.address2');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.country');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.email');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.fax');


          ?>      
                <label>Are you interested in buying property in Malta?</label>
          <?php  
                $interest_buy = array('0'=>'no','1' => 'yes');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.interest_buy_property',array('type'=>'radio','options'=>$interest_buy,'value'=>'0','legend'=>FALSE));
          ?>      
                <label>Are you interested in renting property in Malta?</label>
          <?php  
                $interest_rent = array('0'=>'no','1' => 'yes');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.interest_rent_property',array('type'=>'radio','options'=>$interest_rent,'value'=>'0','legend'=>FALSE));
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.mobile');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.phone');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.postcode');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.town');

                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.newsletter',array('type'=>'checkbox','label'=>'Would you like to register for the newsletter?' ,'checked'=>'1','legend'=>FALSE,));
         ?>       

    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see Arun explanation about what to put in your model first and then, you can use `$this->User->saveAll()`; or `$this->User->saveAssociated();` to save both tables at the same time.

If you want to save ContactDetail first and then save User, You can do this second option, but it is not recomended.

```
 $this->User->ContactDetail->create(); 
 $this->User->ContactDetail->save($this->request->data);`
 this->request->data['User']['contact_detail_id'] = $this->User->ContactDetail->id`;
 $this->User->Create();
 $this->User->save($this->request->data);`
```

But I prefer the first option, to try the first option again,

Note: Make sure ContactDetail and User relationship are there in the model like this in User Model

```
public $hasOne= array(
    'ContactDetail'   => array(
        'className' => 'ContactDetail',         
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_detail_id'
    )
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was wondering how I would save if I need to save contact_detail then user since i kep getting an error  Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`realestate`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `FK_users_contact_details` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_detail_id`) REFERENCES `contact_details` (`contact_detail_id`)

Comment: I edited my answer again for your request, try it and if there is any thing, tell me

Comment: the part seemed to work now I am getting an error on the role_id I am populating it like so in the add  //Populate roles dropdownlist
        $roles = $this->User->Role->find('list',array('order'=>'role'));
        $this->set(compact('roles')); then when I was gonna save i tried this $this->request->data['User']['role_id'] = $roles->data; but it said Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'role_id' cannot be null

Comment: OK scratch what I just said the $belogsto was not set correctly and thus the binding wasn't being done properly. Now i have to see why the aro throwed an error. AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => Role [Aro0.foreign_key] => ) "

Comment: I have accepted your answer as technically it solved my problem your a life saver. Thank you very very much.

Comment: since you where able to identify my problem so quickly I have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081010/acl-error-aro-when-creating-user if you could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: I have put an answer there, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first look into your database, you should use the following database structure, this will help you in a more directions:

`User Model`

```
id
username
password
role_id
```

`ContactDetail Model`

```
id
user_id
address1
address2
```

Define `hasMany` model relationship in the `User` Model with `ContactDetail` like:

```
$hasMany => array('ContactDetail');
```

Now populate an array of Contact details with `(id => address1)` pair using:

```
$this->ContactDetail->find('list', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $user_id)),
                                         'fields' => array('ContactDetail.id', 'ContactDetail.address1')));
```

Now to save an associated details, use [SaveAssociated Method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array).

Comment: mine is hasOne also I think the cake document helped quite a lot thanks I kind of know where to head now.

Comment: I have almost everything working except for the save. I need to save the contact detail first then the user, from within the user add.