# Acl Error (ARO) when creating User

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to save the user but when I save I get the following error

> AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array (
>   [Aro0.model] => Role [Aro0.foreign_key] => ) "

I also get this error in the top

> Undefined index: role_id [CORE\Cake\Model\AclNode.php, line 140]

I don't know what to do as when I added the roles it added them to aros with ease so why is it now giving me problem

I followed the guide provided by

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

which should be simple but it seems its not so simple.

In the **Role** Model

```
public $primaryKey = 'role_id';
public $displayField = 'role';
public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

public function parentNode() {
   return null;
}
```

In the **User** Model

```
public $primaryKey = 'user_id';
public $displayField = 'username';

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password(
          $this->data['User']['password']
        );
        return true;
    }

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Role'   => array(
        'className' => 'Role',         
        'foreignKey' => 'role_id'
            )
        );

public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($this->data['User']['role_id'])) {
            $roleId = $this->data['User']['role_id'];
        } else {
            $roleId = $this->field('role_id');
        }
        if (!$roleId) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array('Role' => array('id' => $roleId));
        }
    }
```

My Save Code for **User**

```
public function add() {                  
//Populate roles dropdownlist        
        $data = $this->User->Role->find('list', array('fields' => array('role_id', 'role')));
        $this->set('roles', $data);

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->ContactDetail->create(); 
            $this->User->ContactDetail->save($this->request->data);
            $this->request->data['User']['contact_detail_id'] = $this->User->ContactDetail->id;
            $this->User->Create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think when saving the user, the behavior tries to save the user's role as the parent ARO for the user's ARO, but the role_id is not being correctly passed. Is your parentNode() returning the roleId correctly? Can you debug what is returned by the parentNode() method when you save a user? The relationship defined in the User model should be User belongsTo Role. The guide that you are referring to will work if you use that code and replace'Group' with 'Role'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jimmy, you should change the relationship to `$belongsTo`. When you save user, it tries to save aros table too so, you need to modify some changes if you don'want user to be saved in aros, only role is enough to be saved aros table (this is also explained in the tutorial), so please see the changes I made in those two models.

Role Model should be:

```
...
    public $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',

        )
    );

    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function parentNode() {
        return null;
    }
    ...
```

User Model should be:

```
...

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Role' => array(
            'className' => 'Role',
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
        )
    );


    public function bindNode($user) {
        return array('model' => 'Role', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['role_id']);
    }
...
```

As shown in the above code, `public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));` should be only on Role model, see the relationship I added and also see parentNode and bindNode function changes.

Try this and contact me if there is anything.

Hope it helps

Comment: will try this as soon as I get home hope it solves my problem.

Comment: I wanted to have the user to save to aros but can't understand why it isn't working. What you provided I had previously done. This only saves the roles to aros.

Comment: But although this will probably be enough for me anyway. I just wanted to know why the other way wasn't working.

Comment: I have accepted you answer although i have a question the user edit if you could so graciously help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115008/cakephp-edit-not-loading-foreign-table-data

Comment: Please vote up my answer too if you accept it, I'll try to answer your other question as soon as possible Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `parentNode()` methods, I am assuming you should change the relationship in the User model as:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Role');
```

Also make sure that $this->request->data['User'] contains the role_id field correctly when calling $this->User->save($this->request->data) in the add action.

And a minor change: Use lowercase 'c' in `$this->User->Create();` :

```
$this->User->create();
```

Comment: the user itself is created with all the data correctly the problem is the automagical creation of aros. Will check again though just in case it is so magical that it still saves.

Comment: I had previously had roles as belongsto but it didn't make much of a difference but will change it back.