# CakePHP Edit Not Loading foreign Table Data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to get my edit to work I need the contact detail data to load when the user data loads. I have set the data in a similar manner to how I am retrieving the list of roles. I also don't know how to retrieve according to the model currently I was hard-coding it to retrieve 28. Would greatly appreciate any help provided.

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    //Populate roles dropdownlist          
    $data = $this->User->Role->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'name')));
    $this->set('roles', $data);

    $data2 = $this->User->ContactDetail->find('first', array(

        'conditions' => array('ContactDetail.id' =>'28')));        
    $this->set('contactdetails', $data2);

    if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

my view is set up in the following manner

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
                echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('role_id');

                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.name');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.surname');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.address1');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.address2');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.country');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.email');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.fax');


          ?>      
                <label>Are you interested in buying property in Malta?</label>
          <?php  
                $interest_buy = array('0'=>'no','1' => 'yes');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.interest_buy_property',array('type'=>'radio','options'=>$interest_buy,'value'=>'0','legend'=>FALSE));
          ?>      
                <label>Are you interested in renting property in Malta?</label>
          <?php  
                $interest_rent = array('0'=>'no','1' => 'yes');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.interest_rent_property',array('type'=>'radio','options'=>$interest_rent,'value'=>'0','legend'=>FALSE));
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.mobile');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.phone');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.postcode');
                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.town');

                echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.newsletter',array('type'=>'checkbox','label'=>'Would you like to register for the newsletter?' ,'checked'=>'1','legend'=>FALSE,));
         ?>       
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

**User Model**

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';

public $displayField = 'username';

public function bindNode($user) {
    return array('model' => 'Role', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['role_id']);
}

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password(
                    $this->data['User']['password']
    );
    return true;
}

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Role' => array('className' => 'Role'));

public $hasOne = array(
    'ContactDetail' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'id'));

public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester', 'enabled' => false));

public function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (isset($this->data['User']['role_id'])) {
        $roleId = $this->data['User']['role_id'];
    } else {
        $roleId = $this->field('role_id');
    }
    if (!$roleId) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return array('Role' => array('id' => $roleId));
    }
}

}
```

**ContactDetail Model**

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $displayField = 'name';
```

Comment: That is weird... Try this: Do the query from my answer (the second code box), and debug it right away. See if any contact details come forward... By the way, if your user id is 13, that means it will bind the contact detail with id 13. If your database structure is different (if you have some user_id field with value 13) then put the relation like that in the model (foreignKey => user_id).

Comment: @Скачот I have a user with id 47 and contactdetail 27 this was due to some errors here and there.

Comment: So, if your tables are already structured like contactdetail.userid is a foreign key to user.id, define that in the user model relation ('foreignKey' => 'user_id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found is by setting

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Role' => array('className' => 'Role')
    ,      'ContactDetail' => array('className' => 'ContactDetail'));
```

This way the contact detail data loads. Although the data once saved does not update contactdetails.

For me to save I used

```
$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)
```

this worked fully

Comment: Wait, for this to work, you must have `contact_detail_id` and `role_id` field in the users table, right?

Comment: @Скачот Yes which is how it is.

Comment: Then it should be belongsTo. Read more about model bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Once your **User** model `hasOne` **ContactDetail**, you don't need retrieve the information twice, since you've done in `$this->request->data` line, all association model will retrieve too.

So, your `Controller` looks like this:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }

    // Roles
    $roles = $this->User->Role->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'name')));
    $this->set(compact('roles');

    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    }
}
```

And your `View`, for **ContactDetail's** fields looks like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('ContactDetail.name');
```

And so for all the fields related to the model `ContactDetail`. You can find more details here: **[Saving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)**.

**User** model:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'ContactDetail' => array(
        'className' => 'ContactDetail',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: @PauoloRodrigues but one user has one contact detail so why should I use hasMany?

Comment: Right, have you make `debug($this->request->data)`? You will find the `ContactDetail` data. BTW, I edited my answer.

Comment: when I implemented you code not even my username started loading.

Comment: Sorry, the correct is `$this->User->read(null, $id)`. I forgot the `null` in first parameter.

Comment: it is loading the user but not contact details. It also loads the roles but the data is null for contact detail.

Comment: So, there's an error in your relationship. Can you update your question to post `User` and `ContactDetail` models?

Comment: I updated my answer with `hasOne` relationship you need in **User** model. If you have a `user_id` field in `contactdetails` table and still doesn't work, I do not know what might be wrong.

Comment: So you got a row in contact detail with user_id set the same as the user id you are trying to get and it doesnt bind? That is very strange...

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you have 1 contact details row for each user. In this case, you need to define in your *User* model:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'ContactDetail' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
    ),
);
```

Like this, your ids will be synced in both tables. If you don't want to make the id a foreign key, you don't have to, it's just a suggestion.

Next, when you retrieve your data in the controller, you can do:

```
$this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$user = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array('ContactDetail'),
));
```

Now I don't know if there is an automated way to do this, but I sort my data manually to fill in the inputs. I am guessing you will get a structure like *array('User' => array(), 'ContactDetail' => array()).*

```
$user['User']['ContactDetail'] = $user['ContactDetail'];
unset($user['ContactDetail']);
$this->request->data = $user;
```

Then in your view just set the fields as the input array:

```
$this->Form->create('User');
$this->Form->input('User.some_user_field');
$this->Form->input('User.ContactDetail.some_contact_detail_field');
```

This should fill in your fields. When you go save your data, if your array is structured like this, you can use *saveAssociated():*

```
$this->User->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
```

**EDIT**

In case your relation is defined as *User hasMany ContactDetail*, then you need to structure your data like this:

```
$this->request->data = array(
    'User' => array(
        // user data
        'ContactDetail' => array(
            [0] => array(
                //contact data
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

And in your view:

```
$this->Form->input('User.ContactData.0.field')
```

This is for 1 row only, If you need more rows on the child table with 1 input, do your logic accordingly.

Comment: In the view, debug $this->request->data and paste the structure

Comment: $request->data(array)
  User(array)
        id49
        contact_detail_id29
        passwordebc65bb3117645bffc9b51be05384d4751f5c76c
        role_id13
        usernameEnzero2
    Role(array)
        id13
        nameAdministrator
    ContactDetail(array)
        id(null)
        address1(null)
        address2(null)
        country(null)
        email(null)
        fax(null)
        interest_buy_property(null)
        interest_rent_property(null)
        mobile(null)
        name(null)
        newsletter(null)
        phone(null)
        postcode(null)
        surname(null)
        town(null)

Comment: As I see this, your contact details are all null (and that is from the query)... does that row even exist in your database?

Comment: Yes there is data in the database as I can see it in mysql.the contactdetailid is 29

Comment: Something is wrong with your relations. Update the question with tables and model structure